# Prevent access to anyone W/o Login credentials while remotely accessing Windows 10 using Teamviewer

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

Can I work remotely on my home laptop [Windows 10] while preventing access to anyone physically in front of it? So, that my dog and/or younger siblings who dont know the login credentials, can't mess with the laptop while i'm working on it remotely.

Windows 10 Home so I can't use RDP

Comment: You cannot prevent somebody from accessing the computer if it isn't locked.  If you are accessing it remotely, what do you care if its locked?  You can't prevent them from kicking you off though, unless the only user account that exists, is one you have complete and total control over.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly make the mistake of leaving out details of what they have researched and attempted so far. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: You question is unclear. 1) What do you mean by locked?  Accessible only via password, or inaccessible at the laptop even with a password when being remotely used? 2) Is the goal only to block input at the laptop, where you don't care if the remote activity is visible on the laptop screen as long as nobody there can access it, or remote activity must be hidden?

Comment: Using RDC, the remote screen will be locked & hidden anyway. You couldn't prevent anyone with an account/password on that machine from kicking you off, but they couldn't see what you were doing on it.

Comment: Firstly, Thank-you all for your responses.

Comment: @Ramhound While using Teamviewer, I'm only able to work with both side in sync. So, how to access home laptop & keep it locked during my remote session.

Comment: I **think** I understand - you simply remote in using RDP. Not TeamViewer. This will lock the account to those 'local' and they will need to log on (and know your credentials, assuming you don't have any guess pass)

Comment: Hey @Dave , I looked up the procedure for RDP.. it says the target pc should have Win Pro,.. but I have Win 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer has some of these features built in. One is disable remote input. If you enable this while you are connecting to the host, then someone at the host cannot use the keyboard or mouse as they are disabled. Secondly, there is an option to blank the display on the host so that what you do with your remote connection cannot be seen by anyone watching your monitors. None of these solutions are entirely fool proof because anyone with physical access to your machine can tamper with it by unplugging the power supply or something like that.

However, these are some measures you can take to tighten up security a little bit. While what I have mentioned here is for TeamViewer, many programs have similar capabilities.

Hope this helps,